# Left translation on $C_b (\mathbb{R})$ is not a strongly continous semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I'm studying strongly continuous semigroups right now with the book *One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations* by Engel, Nagel. In this book there is a small section about the *left translation* operator which is defined for a function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $t\geq 0$ by
\begin{equation*}
(T(t)f)(s):=f(s+t), \ \ s \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
and it was claimed that the operatorfamily $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ does not form a strongly continous semigroup if the underlying function space for $f$ is $(C_b(\mathbb{R}),||\cdot||_{\infty})$ the space of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. So one has to find a function $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}(T(t)f)(s)=f(s)$ does not hold and therefore the strong continuity is not fullfilled but I couldn't think of an example. My guess was to approximate such an $f$ by a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset C_b(\mathbb{R})$ which converges pointwise but not uniformly to $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Take $f(x) = \sin (x^2)$.

Comment: Exactly. Iconic. If you'll pardon my suggesting a tweak, maybe parentheses around the $x^2$ just so that there's no possibility of misunderstanding (although it is already surely very slight.)

Comment: Thank you!  Added the suggested brackets.

Comment: So if we take $f$ as above we obtain $||T(t)f-f||_{\infty}=2$ therefore $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ does not form a $C_0$-Semigroup on $C_b(\mathbb{R})$?